# Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll with async continuationAction

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

What is the right way to link multiple asynchronous tasks together? I want to know that all tasks have succeeded, or that one task failed, and that my "pipeline" failed

```
Task task1 = RunTask1();
Task task2 = RunTask2();

Task task3_isDependentOnTasks1And2 = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
            new[] {task1,task2},
            async tasks => await RunTask3());
```

My experience debugging the code says that RunTask3 never gets awaited.

On the other hand this

```
Task task1 = RunTask1();
Task task2 = RunTask2();

Task task3_isDependentOnTasks1And2 = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
            new[] {task1,task2},
            tasks => RunTask3().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

Seems to work correctly.

Is the 2nd snippet the correct pattern?

Is there a better pattern to achieve my goal?

Comment: Why aren't you using `Task.WhenAll()` ?? Neither option is "correct" when you can write `await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2); await RunTask3();`. If you can't, why? It matters. For example, if the caller is synchronous, you might as well wait for `ContinueWhenAll` to complete then run `RunTask3()`

Comment: If there's a valid reason for `ContinueWhenAll()` you can use just `tasks=>RunTask()` and then call [Unwrap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-taskextensions-unwrap(system-threading-tasks-task((system-threading-tasks-task)))) on the `Task<Task>` this returns. This will give you the `RunTask3` task

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a better pattern to achieve my goal?

Yes. `ContinueWhenAll` is similar to `ContinueWith`; it's a low-level building block and I don't recommend using it. Use `WhenAll` instead:

```
Task task1 = RunTask1();
Task task2 = RunTask2();

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
await RunTask3();
```

If you need the task instead of using `await` at this point in the code, a local `async` method will work fine:

```
Task task1 = RunTask1();
Task task2 = RunTask2();

Task task3_isDependentOnTasks1And2 = Run3When1And2AreDoneAsync();

async Task Run3When1And2AreDoneAsync()
{
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
  await RunTask3();
}
```